# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for while adding data to pieChart dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, pie-chart

i have imbrecated json objects, i am struggling with this error when i try to loop inside PieData to fill pieChart this is my code

```
  var PieData        = [

       for(b in quizs[i].quests[j].reps){
           //quizs[i].quests[j]["quizId"]
        /*   if(quizs[i].quests[j].reps[b]["stat"]==null){
               var l = 1;
           }
           else{
               var l =quizs[i].quests[j].reps[b]["stat"]
           }*/

           {
          {%set h = 'hex'%}        


    value    : 2,
    startAngle: 240,
    color    : '{{h}}',  
    label    : quizs[i].quests[j].reps[b]["rep"]
  },  }        
       ];
```

when i if i try to change to static for => for (var r = 0; r < 2; r++) { 
i always get the same error, any help is appreciatred

Comment: You can't just drop a `for` loop into the middle of an array initializer. That's what the error message means: the keyword `for` does not make any sense there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `for` in array declaration.

```
var PieData = [];
for (var b in quizs[i].quests[j].reps) {
    PieData.push({
        value: 2,
        startAngle: 240,
        color: "{{h}}",
        label: quizs[i].quests[j].reps[b]["rep"]
    });
}
```

`Array#map` will looks cleaner here

```
var PieData = quizs[i].quests[j].reps.map(i => ({
    value: 2,
    startAngle: 240,
    color: "{{h}}",
    label: i.rep
}));
```